# Synchronizing "SensorEvent.timestamp" with "System.nanoTime()" or "SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()"

Tags: android, android-sensors, data-synchronization, android-api-levels, system-identification

**The problem:**

I need to synchronize some data set time-stamped using `System.nanoTime()` with another one time-stamped using `SensorEvent.timestamp`.

**Description:**

I am working on System Identification of a quadcopter. Data acquisition is done using Android API. The input to my system is the pulse width modulation (PWM) which are time-stamped using `System.nanoTime()` with a frequency of 200 Hz.

The output of the system is Androids's sensors measurements which are time-stamped using `SensorEvent.timestamp`.

I've checked many online resources but unfortunately didn't help. Can I access `SensorEvent.timestamp` whenever I want so I time-stamp the inputs using this clock?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid this problem is a bit complicated. `SensorEvent.timestamp` switched from being `System.nanoTime()` to `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()` at some point, but it is unclear when that happened in terms of devices and API levels.  In fact, it appears to be completely manufacturer-dependent: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56561

Furthermore, these clocks count relative to different events or points in time, and `nanoTime()` does not necessarily continue counting in deep sleep mode; [Android: time intervals with deep sleep (System.nanoTime(), System.currentTimeMillis(), SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266441/android-time-intervals-with-deep-sleep-system-nanotime-system-currenttimemi)

The only way we found to solve the problem is to periodically record `System.currentTimeMillis()`, `System.nanoTime()` and `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()` as atomically as possible, and use the offset between `SensorEvent.timestamp` and both `System.nanoTime()` and `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()` to figure out which one the sensor is using.  Once you have that you can get an absolute timestamp for each sensor event adding the delta between your `SensorEvent.timestamp` and `System.nanoTime()` or `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()` (respectively) to your `System.currentTimeMillis()`.  It's not perfect, and could be off by as much as a few millisecond, but it's as good as we could get it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: How valid is the idea that after API 17 we don't need to recalculate time diff after a deep sleep?